# Mono C# access denied to folders I own

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I've written an application in C# that involves enumerating a directory and reading each file. However, on my Linux box, I always get Access Denied when trying to enumerate directories, even ones I own. Here is my code:

```
foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(n => n.EndsWith(".stage")))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {                    
        levels.Add(AenigmaLevel.Deserialize(sr.ReadToEnd()));
    }
}
```

The directory and its parents are chmod 777'd, and even running as root doesn't clear up the issue. There are also no extended attributes set on the directory, as confirmed with lsattr.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

**EDIT** Rookie error: the issue was me trying to open the *directory* rather than the *file*.

Comment: What is the value of `path`?

Comment: @mjwills `path` contains the directory to be enumerated, e.g. `/home/monotron/Levels`

Comment: Check which version of Mono you are using, and then locate the relevant source code, https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs then you should be able to know why.